# Flutter building Windows app warning when objectbox added in pubspec.yaml

Tags: windows, build, suppress-warnings, objectbox

When I start debug or run Flutter app (VS Code) have warning :
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1282 (message):
The DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option was not given and policy CMP0135 is
not set.  The policy's OLD behavior will be used.  When using a URL
download, the timestamps of extracted files should preferably be that of
the time of extraction, otherwise code that depends on the extracted
contents might not be rebuilt if the URL changes.  The OLD behavior
preserves the timestamps from the archive instead, but this is usually not
what you want.  Update your project to the NEW behavior or specify the
DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option with a value of true to avoid this
robustness issue.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/objectbox_flutter_libs/windows/CMakeLists.txt:58 (FetchContent_Declare)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

No matter which the body of main()
Just add in pubspec.yaml to dependencies:
objectbox: ^2.3.1
objectbox_flutter_libs: any

But app has been built and start normally
Maybe someone know what does it meen and how to solve?

I've tried modify pubscpec.yaml even in sample teplete project
but the same result

Comment: This is a deprecation warning that you should be able to ignore. See https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/522. If you have a solution for us, we'll happy to implement it. Otherwise we'll look at this when we have time.